# Importing values from csv gives null value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want the values from csv file to be read using Python27.

I am using the following code:

```
import csv
with open('D:\\data.csv','rb') as file:
    contents = csv.reader(file)
    matrix = list()
    for row in contents:
        matrix.append(row)
    print matrix[1][5]
```

Values will be printed only for first 2*2 matrix (i.e till `matrix[1][1]`).

When I print for `matrix[1][5]` gives a null value.

Inside the csv file i have two columns, i have text data like this:

```
Rocky       manager
Mark        assistant
Peter       tester
Ravi        developer
Sonu        marketing
Iyer        analyst
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you want indices that do not exist to return `None` rather than have it raise an `IndexError`?

Comment: what's inside data.csv? and what do you expect as an output?

Comment: Martijn, In the output i don't see any value.

Comment: @Pierce: you simply have the indices mixed up; the first index is for the row, the second for the column. You'd get an `IndexError` exception, not a 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

First, the word "analyst" will appear as `matrix[5][1]`.

Second, the csv reader by default expects commas between the elements, and it expects exactly one delimiter between elements. For your format you need to set the delimiter to a space, and use `skipinitialspace` to skip the other space characters:

```
contents = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: i got this error:   for row in contents:
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) and i even added csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize) then i got the following error :    csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
TypeError: limit must be an integer

Comment: The OP probably formatted the data into columns for us, they seem to state that `matrix[0][0]` and `matrix[0][1]`, etc. up to `matrix[1][1]` works, so the delimiter is not an issue here.